# Marklogic : search:suggest on phrases

Tags: marklogic

I have following xml structure :

```
<root>
<text>Hi i am a test user and doing testing here. Copied text Let’s suppose we have a text field where the user needs to enter the number of a person id. If the user types 1, all ids starting with 1 will show up. If the user types 12, all ids starting with 12 will show up.</text>
</root>
```

Now i have created field on "text" element and also enabled field word lexicon on it. Executed following query :

```
xquery version "1.0-ml"; 
import module namespace search ="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy"; 
let $options := 
<search:options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
 <default-suggestion-source>
    <word collation="http://marklogic.com/collation//S2">
      <field name="text"/>
    </word>
 </default-suggestion-source>
</search:options>
return
search:suggest("tes", $options, 100)
```

As a result i got "test" and "tseting" as suggestions that is absolutely fine but i too want some more text like in above case i am expecting "test user and doing..." and "testing here...". Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Word lexicons store word tokens, so that's why you're getting individual words returned, rather than phrases. For matching within phrases you could use a range index on `<text>` and for each search suggest entry `concat('*',$term,'*')` so your API call would look like this `search:suggest("*tes*", $options, 100)`.

However, because of the leading wildcard pattern, I think this will slow down your query considerably, and it will also return the whole value of the element, not starting at the position of your search term, i.e.: `Hi i am a test user and doing testing here. Copied text ...` not `test user and doing ...`. You could parse this out programmatically, of course.

For better performance, consider using a chunked element range index strategy. It requires pre-processing and a potentially significant amount of data, depending on the size of the chunk source, but it will achieve the result you want and be very fast and scalable. There is an [excellent blog post over at Avalon consulting](http://blogs.avalonconsult.com/blog/search/auto-complete-in-marklogic-server/) that describes how to do this in detail.

Answer (score 1):

To search for partial phrases, use an opening double quote (the grammar value for ) without a closing quote.
For example: search:suggest('"and th', $options)
"and that"
"and this"
A closing double quote signals the parser that the phrase is complete and
therefore no expanded suggestions are generated. 
Also used with a constraint.

```
search:suggest('constraint:"and th', $options)</search:quotation>
```

=====
from http://docs.marklogic.com/search:suggest